How do you update/reassign a class member Chrono::timestamp for rolling elapse times
Example code did build due to me missing something that was apart of my function implementation.
My function locally was marked as const, and I forgot to include that in the code below.  Also this const marking was also what caused me to see the error below, and took too long for me to realize this.
How do you re-assign a class member chrono time_point variable?
I skimmed through the hour long video from {@Howard Hinnant} and I didn't see anything referencing what I need.
Time Output Class
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
namespace chrono = std::chrono;
namespace chrono_lit = std::chrono_literals;
using namespace chrono_lit;

class TrackTimeElapsed {
  public:
    TrackTimeElapsed(uint64_t interval):
      m_timestamp(chrono::steady_clock::now()), m_interval(interval) {}
    ~TrackTimeElapsed() {}
    void trackTime() const { // Edit @14:15 << Just realized my function was const locally, and that was causing issues.
      chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      auto diff = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - m_timestamp);
      if (diff.count() > m_interval) {
        std::cout << "Time elapsed" << std::endl;
        // Update timestamp to help track when next print out needs to occur.
        m_timestamp = now; // const related error was being experienced here, which makes sense due to my function being const.
      }
    }
  private:
    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> m_timestamp;
    uint64_t m_interval;
};


Here is the error I am getting from attempting to compile:
Class File: error: passing 'const std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point' {aka 'const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >'} as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  105 |         timestamp = now;


You have both TrackTimeElapse and TrackTimeElapsed.  Please provide the real code.

Compiles here with the class name typo fixed. Complete guess: trackTime might be marked const

Why isn't m_interval a duration with a time resolution attached? The way you've written it presumes a very specific time resolution for steady_clock which is platform-dependent.

"Issue here due to assignment operator not being defined." Exactly what error are you getting?

@G.M. I am using example code to keep the problem set concise.  This mirrors what I have in my project.  If you want some context, I am writing a time-based file log that closes and opens a new file after defined set of time has passed since the current file was open.

"// Issue here"  What is the issue??  Your code seems to compile fine for everyone here that has tried it.  This is not a [mre] unless you explain what you were expecting and what actually happened.

What happens when you attempt an assignment to m_interval within trackTime()?  What (if any) is the resultant error message?  Would that be related to the symptoms reported in your question?

I figured out the issue.  My function was declared as const, and it just clicked for me.  Apologies!

@chris If you'll make your comment an answer, I'll upvote it.  I would also hope it would be marked correct.

I'll mark it correct.  But he should also include that this was prior to the update post realization.

@HowardHinnant, Thanks for the ping, I got distracted. Avoiding another ping to the OP, I'm proud to say it's "she" now :)

There's no problem in general with assigning to a time_point (it's just a wrapped number), but per the updated post, trackTime is marked const, so changing members of this isn't allowed.
void trackTime() const {
                 ^^^^^ Remove this

At least to me, the function name suggests that it might modify the object, so lacking const is in line with my expectations.
